Low rank positive semi-definite approximation of a symmetric matrix
Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix. Consider the problem
$$\min \|A-B\|$$
subject to $B\geq 0$ and $\text{rank}(B)\leq r$, where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Frobenius norm. How can I solve this problem?
My idea:
Let $UDU'$ be an eigendecomposition of $A$, where  $D=diag(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_1\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$. Since the Frobenius norm is unitarily invariant the problem above is equivalent to
$$\min \|D-C\|$$
subject to $C\geq 0$ and $\text{rank}(C)\leq r$. The solution to this problem is clearly $C^*=\text{diag}(\max(\lambda_1,0),\dots,\max(\lambda_r,0),0,\dots,0)$. Converting back to the original problem yields the solution
$B^*=UC^*U'$.
Is this correct?

Rather than asking if your solution is correct, perhaps it would be more enlightening to shed some light on the doubts you're having regarding its correctness?
